# Fortran arithmetic error

Tags: loops, math, fortran, integer-arithmetic

I'm having an interesting issue with fortran. Namely, it seems to be making a consistent arithmetic mistake when it tries to multiply 774840977 by 3 and add one, it prints out -1970444364, which obviously enough isn't the right answer.
 Now, I think it's making this same mistake in a few other places but it's hard to find this when it happens. The do loop below normally runs through 1-10,000,000 but the value where this number pops up is n=786431, so I shrunk down the bounds right to that value for your convenience. I assume it's an issue with integer limitations or something like that in fortran, but I'd like to know if there's any way to resolve this in fortran or if I need to try this in something else. For context of what I'm doing here, I'm having it run through collatz chains, you can look those up if curious. [Snapshot of arithmetic steps][[image]

```
      program Collatzthings
  implicit integer*4 (i-o)
  implicit doubleprecision*8 (a-h)
  integer*4 n0

  open(1,file='datac',status='unknown')
  e=0
  do 100 n0=786431,786431
     n=n0
     i=0
     j=0
    do while (n.GT.1)
      if (mod(n,2).EQ.0) then
        n=.5*n
        i=i+1
        j=(j+1)
      elseif (mod(n,2).EQ.1) then
        n=((3*n)+1)
        i=i+1
      endif
      write(6,*)n
    end do
    b=i
    c=j
    a=c/b
pause
    write(1,*)n0,i,a
100 continue
close(1)
stop
1000 format(7(g12.4,1x))
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the wonderful world of integer overflows. The maximum number that can be stored in a (signed<sup>♰</sup>) 4 byte integer is 2,147,483,647 which is less than 2,324,522,932, the result of `3 * 774840977 + 1`

You could declare the variable as an 8-byte integer, then the overflow would only happen at 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

<sup>♰</sup> The Fortran standard does not have unsigned integers